# Generate JSON object from json-path in python

Tags: python, json, jsonpath

I have a list of json path-s and some values for every path, for example:
`bla.[0].ble` with a value: `3`

and I would like to generate a json object where to output will look like this:

```
{
  "bla": [
    {
      "ble":  3
    }
  ]
}
```

To find the expression in the json I used [jsonpath-ng](https://pypi.org/project/jsonpath-ng/) library, but now I want to do the other direction, and build json from json-paths.

Can you give me some advice how make this json-generator, which can be used for every json-path?
I tried to just loop through the keys and create list if needed, but maybe there is a more generic solution for this? (any open source library is also perfect if there is any)

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround my solution was to build a new dictionary using the expressions (or their hash) as keys and the values as the values:

`generated_json[hash(bla.[0].ble)] = 3`

So even though the json object doesn't match the expected output format, I can use this to lookup my expressions as they describe unique paths.
Please feel free to suggest any better solution as this is just a workaround.